# Is there an example of an exponential family distribution with intractable normalizing constant? If so, what is it?

Tags: probability-distributions

Typically, one comes across examples of exponential family distributions that have analytically computable normalizing constants.  Consider the normal, beta, Poisson, etc. distributions.

However, I don't see why the normalizing constant would need to be tractable in general.  Is there an example of an exponential family distribution with intractable normalizing constant?

Comment: What do you mean by exponential family?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is an example that is nothing like the normal, beta, Poisson, etc. distributions

The sample space of the Ising model is based on a graph $G=(V,E)$ specified by a set of vertices $V$ and a set of undirected edges $E$. The sample space is $\{-1,1\}^V$. The density is $$\exp\left(\sum_{i\in V}Q^1_ix_i+\sum_{(i,j)\in E}Q^2_{ij}x_ix_j\right)$$

The natural parameters are $(Q^1, Q^2)\in \mathbb R^V \times \mathbb R^{V\times V}$ and the sufficient statistics are $(x, xx^T)\in \{-1,1\}^V\times \{-1,1\}^{V\times V}$.

The normalizing constant is the complicated function

$$\Lambda(Q^1, Q^2)=\sum _{x\in \{-1,1\}^V}\exp\left(\sum_{i\in V}Q^1_ix_i+\sum_{(i,j)\in E}Q^2_{ij}x_ix_j\right)$$

source: [pg 3 of](http://statweb.stanford.edu/%7Ejtaylo/courses/stats306b/restricted/notebooks/multiparameter_partII.pdf)